add-headers multiline in nginx show error http2
I'm trying to configure one of my add_headers in Nginx and cannot make it multiline.
I think I do it well, but no. When I try, I get an error: ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR.
This work:
add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://www.google-analytics.com https://www.google.com https://www.gstatic.com/; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://fonts.googleapis.com; img-src 'self' data:; object-src 'none'; worker-src 'self' https://castris.com; font-src 'self' https://fonts.googleapis.com https://fonts.gstatic.com; frame-src 'self' https://www.google.com;";

But if use
    add_header Content-Security-Policy "
      default-src 'self';
      script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://www.google-analytics.com https://www.google.com https://www.gstatic.com;
      style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://fonts.googleapis.com;
      img-src 'self' data:;
      object-src 'none';
      worker-src 'self' https://castris.com;
      font-src 'self' https://fonts.googleapis.com https://fonts.gstatic.com;
      frame-src 'self' https://www.google.com;
    ";

Get error in browser error http2 and on logs nginx, don't get anything.
